# MySQL insert if condition met in another table

Tags: php, mysql

Im looking for the appropriate way to insert date into one table based on the value of a field in another table.

Comment: insert into table_a select ANYTHING from table_b where conditions

Comment: Can you be way more specific. The way the value from the external table relates to the insert table may affect the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways, e.g. 
insert into mytable1 (date_field) values(select date_field from mytable2 where pkfield=16)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `INSERT..SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO first_table (...)
    SELECT somevalue FROM second_table WHERE condition;
```

The `SELECT` fields must match the `INSERT` fields. You can add constant columns in the `SELECT` too:

```
SELECT somecolumn, 'constant value' ...
```

to supply values not available in `second_table`.